# Same name controllers, one for admins, one for users. the admin keeps routing to the user. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, admin, store

I am creating a simple store, I have a single product table. I want anyone accessing the store at url 'website/products' to only be able to 'show' products. but on the url 'website/admins/products' I want to create, edit, destroy.

I have two controllers with the same name 'product_controller'. one is in 'controller/admin' the other is just in 'controller'.
the admin controller has full CRUD while the other controller only has show.

My problem is that I am always routed to the same controller ('website/admins/products' sends me to the 'controller/product_controller')

I am not sure if the problem is in my route file or my form (or something else?)

This is my form that is identical for both

```
    <%= form_with( model: product, local: true) do |form| %> 
    <% if product.errors.any? %>  
      <div id="error_explanation">    
        <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>                                                                                                                                                                         
        <ul>                                                                                    
        <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>                                              
          <li><%= message %></li>                                                                
        <% end %>                                                                               
        </ul>                                                                                  
      </div>                                                                                    
    <% end %>                                                                                   

    <div class="field">                                                                         
      <%= form.label :title %>                                                                  
      <%= form.text_field :title %>                                                               
    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                     
    <div class="field">                                                                          
     <%= form.label :description %>                                                            
     <%= form.text_area :description %>                                                          
    </div>                                                                                      

    <div class="field">                                                                         
      <%= form.label :price %>                                                                  
      <%= form.text_field :price %>                                                               
    </div>                                                                                      

    <div class="field">                                                                         
      <%= form.label :inventory_count %>                                                        
      <%= form.number_field :inventory_count %>                                                 
    </div>                                                                                      

    <div class="admin/actions">                                                                 
      <%= form.submit %>                                                                        
    </div>
```

And this is my route file

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do                                                               

   namespace :admin do                                                                          
     resources :products                                                                        
   end                                                                                                                        

   resources :products  
 end
```

Added:

controllers/products_controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.ipdate(product_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @product, notice: 'product was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.json {render :edit }
        format.json {render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :inventory_count)
    end
end
```

controllers/admin/products_controller

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end
    end 
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.ipdate(product_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @product, notice: 'product was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.json {render :edit }
        format.json {render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json {head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :inventory_count)
    end
end
```

Update: View index.html.erb
`24 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>                                                                23                                                                                                 22 <h1>Products</h1>                                                                               21                                                                                                 20 <table>                                                                                         19   <thead>                                                                                       18     <tr>                                                                                        17       <th>Title</th>                                                                            16       <th>Description</th>                                                                      15       <th>Price</th>                                                                            14       <th>Inventory count</th>                                                                  13       <th colspan="3"></th>                                                                     12     </tr>                                                                                       11   </thead>                                                                                      10                                                                                                  9   <tbody>                                                                                        8     <% @products.each do |product| %>                                                            7       <tr>                                                                                       6         <td><%= product.title %></td>                                                            5         <td><%= product.description %></td>                                                      4         <td><%= product.price %></td>                                                            3         <td><%= product.inventory_count %></td>                                                  2         <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>                                                  1         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_product_path(product) %></td>                       25          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }     %></td>                                                                                         1       </tr>                                                                                      2     <% end %>                                                                                    3   </tbody>                                                                                       4 </table>                                                                                         5                                                                                                  6 <br>                                                                                             7                                                                                                  8 <%= link_to 'New Product', new_admin_product_path %>`

If you have any thoughts or suggestions I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code for the controllers?

Answer (score 1):

The routes are not the problem, if you run rails routes with that code you can see something like:

```
    admin_products GET    /admin/products(.:format)          admin/products#index
                   POST   /admin/products(.:format)          admin/products#create
 new_admin_product GET    /admin/products/new(.:format)      admin/products#new
edit_admin_product GET    /admin/products/:id/edit(.:format) admin/products#edit
     admin_product GET    /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#show
                   PATCH  /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#update
                   PUT    /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#update
                   DELETE /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#destroy
          products GET    /products(.:format)                products#index
                   POST   /products(.:format)                products#create
       new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)            products#new
      edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)       products#edit
           product GET    /products/:id(.:format)            products#show
                   PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)            products#update
                   PUT    /products/:id(.:format)            products#update
                   DELETE /products/:id(.:format)            products#destroy
```

If you want to use different controllers you need two forms that generates routes to those controllers respectively

```
<%= form_with scope: :product, url: product_path(@product), method: :patch do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

For admin

```
<%= form_with scope: :product, url: admin_product_path(@product), method: :patch do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**Update**

For new products

```
<%= form_with scope: :product, url: products_path do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= form_with scope: :product, url: admin_products_path do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Api reference https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: I think this is definitely a step in the right direction, however this error now pops up when I try to add a new_product 
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/products", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`  Id should not be required for a new product yet because it hasn't been created?